# inheritance memory management managing

Tags: c++, inheritance

```
class base
{
public:
   base() : buffer(NULL) {}
private:
   unsigned char * buffer;
};

class msgA : public base
{
public:
   msgA() 
   {
       //alocate memory for buffer size X
       this->buffer = new (std::nothrow) unsigned char[A_MSG_SIZE]; // A_MSG_SIZE = 20
   }
};

class msgA2 : public msgA
{
   msgA2() 
   {
       //alocate memory for buffer size X2
       this->buffer = new (std::nothrow) unsigned char[A2_MSG_SIZE]; // A2_MSG_SIZE = 30
   }
};
```

1. is there a memory leak in msgA2 constructor?
2. whats the best way to design this without causing any issue?

should I delete buffer then allocate a new one in class msgA2 because msgA constructor were called previously

**edit**: there is a destructor delete []

I added the following to the constructors

```
if(this->buffer != NULL)
{
    delete [] this->buffer ;
    this->pMsgBuffer = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Multiple inheritance is when you inherit from more than one class *for one class*. Is buffer going to be a string? Why not use `std::string`?

Comment: 1. There is no class named `ClassA2` in your example. If you mean `msgA2`, then yes, unless it first frees the memory allocated by `msgA` constructor. 2. Hard to tell, seeing as you haven't specified any design goals.

Comment: oh ok, thanks, it is a plain char array with different size depending on the message, each message could have a bunch of variables, and mini buffers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let `base` allocate the memory, passing the buffer size as arguments for the constructors. Something like

```
class base
{
protected:
   base(size_t size) { /* allocate */ }
   unsigned char * buffer;
};

class msgA : public base
{
public:
   msgA() : base(X)
   {
   }
protected:
   msgA(size_t size) : base(size) 
   {
   }
};

class msgA2 : public msgA
{
public:
   msgA2() : msgA(X2)
   {
   }
};
```

This way you could have `base` manage the memory (and delete the buffer in the destructor).

Comment: I like that allocation/deallocation moved to the base

Answer (score 2):

*"is there a memory leak in ClassA2 constructor?"*

Currently as your code stands, there's no memory allocation and therefore no memory leak. Yet I worry about the way you are going to allocate the memory for you `buffer` member. Will it be in constructor? Will there be a need for a destructor that will be explicitly taking care of this memory? If you have to implement *destructor*, don't forget about *copy constructor* and *assignment operator* ([*Rule of Three*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4172722/1168156)).

*"whats the best way to design this without causing any issue?"*

The best is to avoid handling memory management on your own. Use `std::vector<unsigned char>` for binary data or `std::string` if it is a string.